# Calculate geographic distance between points using NetTopologySuite

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, gis, nettopologysuite

I am trying to calculate distance between two points using NetTopologySuite. Since I am referencing Microsoft documentation, I Came up with following GeometryExtension and GeometryHelper classes:

```
        public static class GeometryExtensions
    {
        private static readonly CoordinateSystemServices _coordinateSystemServices = new CoordinateSystemServices(new Dictionary<int, string>
            {
                // Coordinate systems:

                [4326] = GeographicCoordinateSystem.WGS84.WKT,

                // CRS for Denmark ESPG 25832. Source: https://epsg.io/25832 and https://sdfe.dk/
                [25832] = @"PROJCS[""ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N"",
                                GEOGCS[""ETRS89"",
                                    DATUM[""European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989"",
                                        SPHEROID[""GRS 1980"",6378137,298.257222101,
                                            AUTHORITY[""EPSG"",""7019""]],
                                        TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                                        AUTHORITY[""EPSG"",""6258""]],
                                    PRIMEM[""Greenwich"",0,
                                        AUTHORITY[""EPSG"",""8901""]],
                                    UNIT[""degree"",0.0174532925199433,
                                        AUTHORITY[""EPSG"",""9122""]],
                                    AUTHORITY[""EPSG"",""4258""]],
                                PROJECTION[""Transverse_Mercator""],
                                PARAMETER[""latitude_of_origin"",0],
                                PARAMETER[""central_meridian"",9],
                                PARAMETER[""scale_factor"",0.9996],
                                PARAMETER[""false_easting"",500000],
                                PARAMETER[""false_northing"",0],
                                UNIT[""metre"",1,
                                    AUTHORITY[""EPSG"",""9001""]],
                                AXIS[""Easting"",EAST],
                                AXIS[""Northing"",NORTH],
                                AUTHORITY[""EPSG"",""25832""]]"
            }
        );
        


        /// <summary>
        /// Projects a geometry to another SRID
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="geometry"></param>
        /// <param name="targetSrid"></param>
        /// <param name="defaultSourceSrid">If the geometry SRID has not been specified (i.e. equals 0) defaultSourceSrid is used</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Geometry ProjectTo(this Geometry geometry, int targetSrid, int? defaultSourceSrid = null)
        {
            if (geometry == null)
                throw new Exception("Geometry is null, cannot project");

            var sourceSrid = geometry.SRID == 0 && defaultSourceSrid.HasValue ? defaultSourceSrid.Value : geometry.SRID;
            var transformation = _coordinateSystemServices.CreateTransformation(sourceSrid, targetSrid);

            var result = geometry.Copy();
            result.Apply(new MathTransformFilter(transformation.MathTransform));

            return result;
        }
}




     public  class GeometryHelper
    {
        private static readonly int _longLatSRID = 4326;
        private static readonly int _targetSRID = 25832;

        /// <summary>
        /// In order to get the distance in meters, we need to project to an appropriate
        /// coordinate system. If no SRID is provided 25832, which covers Denmark is used.
        /// If the provided Points have no SRID, 4326 (longitude/latitude) is assumed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="a"></param>
        /// <param name="b"></param>
        /// <param name="targetSrid"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static double DistanceInMeters(Point a, Point b, int? targetSrid = null)
        {
            targetSrid ??= _targetSRID;

            try
            {
                //If SRID is not set, assume long/lat, ie. 4326
                return a.ProjectTo(targetSrid.Value, _longLatSRID).Distance(b.ProjectTo(targetSrid.Value, _longLatSRID));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to calculate distance", e);
            }
        }
}
```

To test if my distance is being calculated properly, I opened Google Maps and selected the calculate distance between 3 different pairs of points. Then I copy pasted the values in my tests to see if they match. The values I am getting from my code is 2 times larger than what I am getting from Google Maps. What am I doing wrong? Here are my tests:

```
public class GeometryHelperTests
{
    [Theory]
    [InlineData(55.676518126293466, 12.567203858066554, 55.67645068023813, 12.56698376863065, 15.68)]//I am getting 36.1
    [InlineData(55.659368700924475, 12.546625254609248, 55.65940085355421, 12.546601114728679, 3.77)]//I am getting 6.2
    [InlineData(55.65896978705746, 12.546674114514795, 55.6596855501795, 12.547258269821455, 87.09)]//I am getting 173.7
    public void DistanceInMeters(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double expected)
    {
        // setup
        Point point1 = new Point(x1, y1) { SRID = 4326 };
        Point point2 = new Point(x2, y2) { SRID = 4326 };

        //CoordinateSystemFactory csFact = new CoordinateSystemFactory();
        

        // act
        var result = GeometryHelper.DistanceInMeters(point1, point2);

        

        // assert
        result.Should().Be(expected);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to calculate `great circle distance`.
NetTopologySuite `Point.Distance` method returns the `cartesian distance`.

Try the following:

```
public static double Radians(double x)
{
    return x * Math.PI / 180;
}

public static double GreatCircleDistance(double lon1, double lat1, double lon2, double lat2)
{
    double R = 6371e3; // m

    double sLat1 = Math.Sin(Radians(lat1));
    double sLat2 = Math.Sin(Radians(lat2));
    double cLat1 = Math.Cos(Radians(lat1));
    double cLat2 = Math.Cos(Radians(lat2));
    double cLon = Math.Cos(Radians(lon1) - Radians(lon2));

    double cosD = sLat1*sLat2 + cLat1*cLat2*cLon;

    double d = Math.Acos(cosD);

    double dist = R * d;

    return dist;
}
```

You can also use the built-in [`GeoCoordinate.GetDistanceTo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.location.geocoordinate.getdistanceto?view=netframework-4.8) which implements the [Haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) formula that is more accurate for small distances.

Answer (score 1):

Even though saeedkazemi's answer is correct and gives results closer to the real value, results given by my code were also quite close, but I figured out that I had to flip the coordinates given by Google maps. So if I was given 55.6765, 12.5672 I need to give 12.5672,55.6765 to the formula. That being said, saeedkazemi's answer provides results closer to the real value.